# Access Denied for listobjects

Tags: amazon-s3

I am getting error when trying to list objects with cross account bucket policy applied

```
 aws s3 ls bucket-name

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

Bucket Policy used to allow list object is :

```
{
  "Id": "Policy2",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt13",
      "Action": [ "s3:GetBucketLocation", "s3:ListBucket" ,"s3:GetBucketPolicy"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"],
      "Principal": {"AWS":"*"}
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried specifying the principal to a specific ARN. Assuming the block public access is enabled. But that doesn't work either.

Comment: Is your block-public-access is on? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html

Comment: I have tried specifying the principal to a specific ARN. Assuming the block public access is enabled. But that doesn't work either.

Comment: What is the IAM policy for the user?

Comment: What do you mean by "cross account bucket policy applied"?

Answer (score -1):

Your policy worked fine for me!

The steps I took:

- Created a new bucket
- Turned OFF **Block Public Access** for the two *Bucket Policy* options
- Added your bucket policy (above), changing my bucket name
- Used an IAM User from a *different account* to list the bucket

It worked fine.